# Убрать гласные из строки

Tags: python, строки

Нужно убрать гласные из строки. Есть более лёгкие способы, но я хочу узнать, почему именно этот не даёт нужный результат.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
   text = list(text)
   for i in text:
       if i in 'aeiouAEIOU':
          text.remove(i)
   return str(''.join(text))
```

Если его применять к фразам 'Hey look Words!', 'Hello Mia', он оставляет последнюю гласную букву. А, например, с фразами 'Hello Mama', 'Hello world' работает нормально. В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

Если вам чисто с познавательными целями, то вот так будет работать всегда:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
   text = list(text)
   for i in text[::-1]:
       if i in 'aeiouAEIOU':
          text.remove(i)
   return str(''.join(text))


print(anti_vowel('Hello world'))
print(anti_vowel('Ah, Hello Mama'))
print(anti_vowel('Hey look Words!'))
print(anti_vowel('Hello Mia'))
```

Результат:

```
Hll wrld
h, Hll Mm
Hy lk Wrds!
Hll M
```

Причина - нельзя изменять итерируемый объект в самом цикле, как минимум ту его часть, которая еще будет обрабатываться. При обратном направлении итерации такого изменения не возникает.

Answer (score 3):

Когда Вы пытаетесь удалить гласную букву, то после удаления `i` начинает указывать на следующую букву, после чего тут же происходит вызов уже позаследующей буквы. Стоит ли говорить, что та следующая буква, которую мы получили в `i` после удаления текущей гласной, тоже могла быть гласной...

Как вариант могу предложить следующее: при получении очередной гласной буквы, раз уж Вы обратили текст в список массива, необходимо поменять элемент списка, имеющий индекс той самой гласной буквы, в пустую строку `''`. Так и гласная буква уберётся, и пропусков никаких не будет, и все буквы спокойно пройдут через цикл с проверкой.

```py
def anti_vowel(text):
   text = list(text)
   for i in text:
       if i in 'aeiouAEIOU':
          text[text.index(i)] = ''
   return str(''.join(text))
```

А вообще можно поступить ещё проще: просто пройтись по строке гласных букв и заменить их ВСЕ через [`replace()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.replace/).

```py
def anti_vowel(text):
  vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
  for vowel in vowels:
    text = text.replace(vowel, '')
  return text
```

Answer (score 3):

А если сделать вот так, то всё вдруг заработает:

```
for i in text.copy():
```

Удалять что-то из коллекции, по которой вы сейчас итерируетесь - опасное дело, указатель цикла съезжает. А вот если сделать копию и итерироваться по ней, то уже ничего не съезжает. Но есть и другие способы это обойти, описанные в других ответах.

Answer (score 1):

Вы так или иначе перебираете всю строку, так кладите все что не относится к `aeiouAEIOU` как резульат в другую

```py
def anti_vowel(text):
    to_remove = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    result = ''
    for letter in text:
        if letter not in to_remove:
            result += letter
    return result
```

Или через [list comprehesions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join([letter for letter in text if letter not in 'aeiouAEIOU'])
```